# Saved The Image, But Forgot To Pack The Image To The Blender File

Tags: texture-painting, packed-data

I finished texture painting some cargo pants onto my 3D model and saved the texture as an image, but forgot to pack the image to the blender file.

Once I realized this, I went back into the project and could not get the recently saved image to re-apply or show up on the 3D model.

Is there anyway in Blender to re-apply saved textures to their parent model?

Comment: Are you using Blender Render or Cycles materials? If you use Blender Render, then simply open the image in the UV/Image Editor while the model is in edit mode, and make sure the material texture stack has the image as a texture there with UV mapping. If it is Cycles, almost the same thing except you can navigate the the image texture from within the image texture node in the material node tree. Pack after you get it to show in the viewport on the model.

Comment: Actually the same day I asked this question I had played around with the node editor a bit and realized that same connection you're talking about. Like you said, through using the node editor you can basically re-apply the "image texture" by linking it to the other nodes. Thank you very much for your help.